# How to prevent sidebar shrink when console open

Tags: html, css

My current page looks like:

[image]

However, when I open console, I get this word overflow on "Dashboard"

[image]

Currently, the sidebar's width is set to `12%`, a.k.a a relative width because of varying monitor sizes that may visit the site. Is there a way to prevent the sidebar from shrinking when I open console?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should write a `min-width: value in px`

Answer (score 1):

Because you set it to a relative weight, any change in the width of the page will affect the width of the sidebar.

What you need to do is add a css rule to define the minimum width of the sidebar:

```
#sidebar {
  // [...]
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

As a general rule, only use percentage-based values when you explicitly control the containing element's width, as otherwise you run into the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Great, thanks. :) Now that the sidebar is set though, some text I have in the body is being pushed over by the console and is getting cut off. Can I make the console cover the right side of the body instead of pushing the left side into the sidebar?

Comment: @Chara it all depends on the exact rules you have in place and how you are placing the two sections next to each other (floats or inline blocks).

Comment: they are floating, sidebar has float:left and body has float:right